# Download FTP directory contents to ios

Tags: ios, xcode, ftp

I have a website, let's say it's "http://www.jwilkthings.com/stuff"

I have a bunch of .txt files stored on this website, i.e. "http://www.jwilkthings.com/stuff/text1.txt"

What I'm wanting to do is find a way in iOS to download all of those text files without knowing what the document name is.  I can already retrieve them manually as long as I have a file name, but I would rather just get all of them at once and put them in the documents directory if possible.  I currently use FileZilla to upload all of the text files, so I can use FTP if needed.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to solve this problem is to not use FTP (riddled with performance and security issues), and to configure your web server to expose a table of contents [directory listing](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings) that your client can parse.

But that's not an answer to your question.
If you really want your iOS app to speak FTP, take a look at the [SimpleFTP sample project from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html).

It's old, but I just got it to build on iOS 5. The [ListController.m](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Listings/ListController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009243-ListController_m-DontLinkElementID_11) file has the code you're looking for.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that, it looks useful.  I'm not opposed to configuring my webserver in the way you described, I'm just not sure how I would go about doing it.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, that's why I made the link to Apache directory listing documentation - it's mostly a matter of adding `+Indexes`