# How to list directory contents of ftp via AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, ftp, afnetworking

I need to get list of files stored on FTP. How can i do it with AFNetworking. I already looked at SimpleFTPSample, but is there simplier solution?

Comment: Similar question over here mentions the specific applicable code from SimpleFTPSample http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407238/download-ftp-directory-contents-to-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FTP Helper](https://github.com/erica/iphone-3.0-cookbook-/tree/master/C13-Networking/15-FTP%20Helper) class is the simplest most complete FTP code I could find. The class will work on OS X or iOS.