# How can I get the whole file directory from server using Xcode?

Tags: ios, webserver, download

I am a newbie of Xcode. I want to ask is there a way that I can using Xcode to construct an apps that run in iPod, and it can get all the file from a specific folder in my server.

Say, I want to get all the files(including file and folder) from
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/image/
Where /image/ folder contains at least two folder, and each folder contains many image files, which the number of files is not known, and change frequently, 
e.g. /image/a/  and /image/b/ , both have 1.png, 2.png ....etc

Is there a way to get "ALL" files in the specific directory?

If there really a method that can get all the files, where the files will put when I run the apps? Also, can I use the same files and folder name on my app's side? i.e. /a/1.png , /b/1.png etc.

Comment: I think that you needed something like this:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/10407542/2398911

Comment: So.. I need to connect the folder to a FTP service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an API on the server that you can call from the app.

It's easy to create a restful API using PHP (or Python, Ruby, etc.) that would list the contents of a directory and send the list to the client on request. Use `NSURLConnection` on the app side to make the request.

Consider sending results in JSON format and parse them on the app with `NSJSONSerialization` class.

Alternatively, consider creating a sitemap that you can download, but you'll need to keep it updated on the server side. You could also create the sitemap dynamically in code, again with PHP (Python, Ruby, etc.).